# Borrowing in a foreign currency

Tags: money, lending-interest-ribbis

If someone borrows money from a friend, and later reimburses him using a different country's money, how can he make sure there are no halahik complications, such as making interest? Based on what rate should he reimburse him? The rate on day of the loan? of the repayment?

Comment: Where are you and your friend at the time of borrowing and the time of repayment?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9217 . See also [this article](http://www.dinonline.org/2010/02/23/lending-shekel-for-dollars). This is a complicated topic, so you would be well advised to [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR).

Comment: I read this article from the above answer: http://www.ou.org/ou/print_this/64160

Comment: @DoubleAA My friend will remotely give me USD while I am in the US, and I will give him back NIS when we will be both in Israel. - My understanding from the article is that I will use the rate from the day I reimburse him.